# How do I allow users to rearrange the fields order during content creation?

Tags: entities

Assume I have a *content type* with fields `a`, `b`, `c`.

How to allow users to **rearrange fields** (when they create one content) if they want to display fields in another order? Like b,a,c or c,b,a, etc ...

EDIT:
[Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) do the job for my case.
There is a bug when trying to save the display. But getting both the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) modules in latest dev version fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want per-node changing of field display order I recommend looking at [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) module. It takes over view modes at the level of entity bundles (content types) and additionally individual entities.

It is not an exact fit of what you describe in that:

- It works on an interface separate from content creation.
- It is view
  mode specific. So rearranging one view mode (teaser) will not change
  the full view mode. That might be good or bad depending on what you
  want.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I need. Just a clarification for your second point please, I am not sure to understand: For example, if an user create a content of type "article" and rearrange its fields display order thanks to Panelizer, the other contents of type "article" will not have their fields display order rearranged (it's what I want), right?

Comment: I tested, it is exactly what i needed (and even more!), thanks again Steve.